# Entity Framework Code First DTO or Model to the UI?

Tags: wcf, model, entity-framework-4.1, dto

I am creating a brand new application, including the database, and I'm going to use Entity Framework Code First. This will also use WCF for services which also opens it up for multiple UI's for different devices, as well as making the services API usable from other unknown apps.

I have seen this batted around in several posts here on SO but I don't see direct questions or answers pertaining to Code First, although there are a few mentioning POCOs. I am going to ask the question again so here it goes - do I really need DTOs with Entity Framework Code First or can I use the model as a set of common entities for all boundaries? I am really trying to follow the YAGNI train of thought so while I have a clean sheet of paper I figured that I would get this out of the way first.

Thanks,
Paul Speranza

Answer (score 2):

There is no definite answer to this problem and it is also the reason why you didn't find any.

Are you going to build services providing CRUD operations? It generally means that your services will be able to return, insert, update and delete entities as they are = you will always expose whole entity or single exactly defined serializable part of the entity to all clients. But once you do this it probably worth to check WCF Data Services.

Are you going to expose business facade working with entities? The facade will provide real business methods instead of just CRUD operations. These buisness methods will get some data object and decompose it to multiple entities in wrapped business logic. Here it makes sense to use specific DTO for every operation. DTO will transfer only data needed for the operation and return only date allowed to the client.

Very simple example. Suppose that your entities keep information like `LastModifiedBy`. This is probably information you want to pass back to the client. In the first scenario you have single serializable set so you will pass it back to the client and client pass it modified back to the service. Now you must verify that client didn't change the field because he probably didn't have permissions to do that. You must do it with every single field which client didn't have permission to change. In the second scenario your DTO with updated data will simply not include this property (= specialized DTO for your operation) so client will not be able to send you a new value at all.

It can be somehow related to the way how you want to work with data and where your real logic will be applied. Will it be on the service or on the client? How will you ensure that client will not post invalid data? Do you want to restrict passing invalid data by logic or by specific transferred objects?

Comment: Ladislav, all logic will be in the business layer behind the services. The clients will be as dumb as I can make them, but I will validate the data as much as I can on the client as well as in the business layer.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend a dedicated view model.

Doing this means:

- You can [design the UI (and iterate on it) without having to wait to design the data model first.](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500/)
- There is less friction when you want to change the UI.
- You can avoid security problems with auto-mapping/model binding "accidentally" updating fields which shouldn't be editable by the user -- just don't put them in the view model.

However, with a WCF Data Service, it's hard to ignore the advantage of being able to write the service in essentially one line when you expose entities directly. So that might make the most sense for the WCF/server side.

But when it comes to UI, you're "gonna need it."

Comment: Craig, I'm leaning towards a view model but I am also trying to figure out what should come from the services. Would the services expose the code first model or the view model?

Comment: A data service would expose entities or DTOs, not view models. View models are for UI (Web, WPF, etc.) apps.

Answer (score 0):

> do I really need DTOs with Entity Framework Code First or can I use the model as a set of common entities for all boundaries?

Yes, the same set of `POCOs` / `entities` can be used for all boundaries.

But a set of mappers / converters / configurators will be needed to adapt entities to some generic structures of each layer.

For example, when entities are configured with `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes, `WCF` is able to transfer domain objects' state without creating any special classes.

Similarly, when entities are mapped using `Entity Framework` fluent mapping api, `EF` is able to persist domain objects' state in database without creating any special classes.

The same way, entities can be configured to be used in any layer by means of the layer infrastructure without creating any special classes.